# peewee + MySQL, How to create a custom field type that wraps SQL-built ins?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, peewee

I'd like to create a custom UUID field in peewee (over MySQL).

In python, I'm using the UUID as a hexified string, e.g.:

`uuid = '110e8400-e29b-11d4-a716-446655440000'`

But I want to store it in the database to a column of type `BINARY(16)` to save space.

MySQL has built-in `HEX()` and `UNHEX()`methods to convert back and forth between a string and binary.

So my question is how do I tell peewee to generate SQL that uses a built-in function?  Here's an idea for the code I want to work:

```
class UUIDField(Field):
    db_field='binary(16)'

    def db_value(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            uuid = value.translate(None, '-')   # remove dashes
            # HERE: How do I let peewee know I want to generate
            # a SQL string of the form "UNHEX(uuid)"?

    def python_value(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            # HERE: How do I let peewee know I want to generate
            # a SQL string of the form "HEX(value)"?
```

Note that I'm specifically asking how to get peewee to wrap or unwrap a value in custom SQL.  I realize I could probably do the value conversion entirely in python, but I'm looking for the more general-purpose SQL-based solution.

EDIT: For future reference, here is how I made it work doing the conversions in python.  It doesn't answer the question though, so any ideas are appreciated!

```
import binascii
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase(
    'database',
    fields={'binary(16)': 'BINARY(16)'}     # map the field type
)

# this does the uuid conversion in python
class UUIDField(Field):
    db_field='binary(16)'

    def db_value(self, value):
        if value is None: return None

        value = value.translate(None, '-')
        value = binascii.unhexlify(value)

        return value

    def python_value(self, value):
        if value is None: return None

        value = '{}-{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(
            binascii.hexlify(value[0:4]),
            binascii.hexlify(value[4:6]),
            binascii.hexlify(value[6:8]),
            binascii.hexlify(value[8:10]),
            binascii.hexlify(value[10:16])
        )

        return value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [SelectQuery](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#SelectQuery) you can invoke internal [SQL functions](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#sql-functions-subqueries-and-raw-expressions) like so:

```
from peewee import SelectQuery

# this does the uuid conversion in python
class UUIDField(Field):
    db_field = 'binary(16)'

    def db_value(self, value):
        if value is None: return None

        value = value.translate(None, '-')
        query = SelectQuery(self.model_class, fn.UNHEX(value).alias('unhex'))
        result = query.first()
        value = result.unhex
        return value

    def python_value(self, value):
        if value is None: return None
        query = SelectQuery(self.model_class, fn.HEX(value).alias('hex'))
        result = query.first()
        value = '{}-{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(
            result.hex[0:8],
            result.hex[8:12],
            result.hex[12:16],
            result.hex[16:20],
            result.hex[20:32]
        )
        return value
```